# F4u race wing design

Tags: wing

Can anyone suggest a good airfoil for racing the F4U Corsair? I'm building an RC model but I want it to be fast unlike scale warbird. Any suggestions on wing design and airfoil would be greatly appreciated. I know I can always throw more power to it but I want the fuselage and wing designed to match.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you already asked this question: [I need help designing a modern race wing for the f4u Corsair](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73356/i-need-help-designing-a-modern-race-wing-for-the-f4u-corsair) Because that question was closed as too broad, this one probably will be too, unless you can be much more specific somehow.

Comment: I'm very new to aerodynamics and I'm just looking for a good airfoil that would be thinner and faster. I would rather have someone suggest a good airfoil rather than me just trying to make up something on my own. It shouldn't matter if I'm building a full size plane or an RC model.

Comment: Of course it does matter. Look into Reynolds number and scaling laws. What I wonder is if you want to build a fast model or a F-4U scale model with a different airfoil. Please explain, after having looked into the aforementioned topics. BTW, cool to have an F100 expert on this site!

Comment: Consider posting this question to the "Modeling Science" subforum of www.rcgroups.com.  You may get some useful replies there.

Comment: As I said earlier I'm just learning about aerodynamics and I have no idea how to figure out what the Reynolds number would be for just such an airplane. I plan to keep the wingspan between 40 and 45 in. I also want to maintain the gullwing design and shape. I built a lot of race cars in my day so I'm trying to build a sleeper LOL. I want it to look scale but I wanted to be extremely fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MH 24](https://www.mh-aerotools.de/airfoils/mh24koo.htm) airfoil has been popular for years at international radio-control pylon racing events.  Just ensure that your chord and airspeed give you a Reynolds number exceeding 400,000.

Because airfoils designed for high speed often work poorly at low speed, consider equipping your model with flaps, to make landing easier.

At lower Reynolds numbers, the [Eppler E220](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=e220-il) has a good reputation.  It's also easier to build (more tolerant of inaccuracies) than airfoils in the mostly-laminar-flow MH series.